# How to specify Header attributes in apiary documentation

Tags: rest, apiary.io

Starting with Apiary, I'm currently specifying the APIs for our project.
I was able to define the definitions for the API and defining the parameters works great.
[image]

Now I would like to add also the values passed in the HTTP Headers into my documentation (like pagination, version number of the API,...)

When browsing through the documentation I found that headers could be adden within the payload block or the request block, but I want them to be displayed in the documentation.

Is this possible and what's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can now use the [Headers section](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#headers-section).

Comment: Where do I write the documentation / description for a header entry? The documentation doesn't mention it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Parameters are actually not required to be present in the URL template.

Thus, what you can do is to just have

```
+ Parameters
    + id (required, number, `1`) ... Numeric `id` of the Note to perform action with. Has example value.
    + X-My-Header (required, number, `5469`) ... My header does something
```

and this is going to be rendered in the table you mentioned as well.

You are going to have a warning from the parser, but it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I could do it like this, but I assume there is no way to make a distinction between parameters and header values that is foreseen in apiary? This way I'm abusing a bit the parameters  table off course...

Comment: Yes, there isn't a way to do such distinction yet. It is planned as [Parametric Headers Description](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/26), but it isn't implemented yet.